# How to reduce the distance between the two div

Tags: html, css, margin, padding

I have created a site [WDguideline.com](http://www.wdguideline.com/), there are many div's in it. Problems are how div's will be more distant than this distance. 
 
How to reduce the distance between the divisions? 
Live link : [CSS Basic Skill Tester](http://www.wdguideline.com/css/)

My all DIV CSS:

```
.qd1 {
width: 45%;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
margin: 5px;
float: left;
height: auto;
```

my site photo:

[image: div img]

Comment: Giving your website is good, giving us a working example with code is better.

Comment: Padding, Margin or line breaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you use bootstrap grids this is very easy way.
**xs** (for phones - screens less than 768px wide).
**sm** (for tablets - screens equal to or greater than 768px wide).
**md** (for small laptops - screens equal to or greater than 992px wide).
**lg** (for laptops and desktops - screens equal to or greater than 1200px wide).
Contains 12 grid (column wise) in single row divide the column according to your needs.
Set the grids to 4 for questions and 2 for ads.
Here is the code

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    Question 1 
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    Question 2      
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    Question 1 
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    Question 2      
  </div>
</div>
```

[Check for more information](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_basic.asp)
**I hope it will help you**

Answer (score 0):

From inspecting your website I can find this in `exam_style.css:566`

```
.qd1 {
    width: 45%;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 5px;
    float: left;
    height: auto;
}
```

The `margin` property determines how much distance you want outside of your selector (`.qd1` in this case, which is your div's class).

Simply set the `margin` to 0 (or something lower than 5px) and you'll see your divs getting closer.

Now, as a side-note, when providing a working instance as example for your question, better use tools like JSFiddle, CodePen, etc. This way, the question will still have the reference when your website changes content (and it most probably will over the years).